# A horizontal line while booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

I just did my first installation of dual boot ubuntu on a separate drive than my windows OS.
But everytime I boot into Ubuntu I see a  weird horizontal line across the screen just before and after "Enter password" screen.

[image: Image of the problem]

I found a similar query but many years old being something related to NVIDIA's drivers.
I am very new to all this so please guide me how can I fix that glitchy pixel line.
I am using Lenovo legion with GTX 1650 and i5 10300H.
( I did create a new EFI partition on the separate drive than windows and also tried reinstalling ubuntu after disabling secure boot)

Comment: Yes, you need to disable Secure Boot in order to use the Nvidia proprietary drivers. No, you don't need an additional EFI partition (no problem if in a different drive, just a waste of space. Now, regarding the problem, does it persist after logging in?

Comment: Yes, I disabled the secure boot. The problem is there only while booting up, once I login into the system there is no horizontal line after that.

Comment: So, not really a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching NVIDIA drivers fixed this issue.
Initially I was using "nvidia-driver-460", which was the recommended version by Ubuntu.
But I randomly tried changing it just to experiment and set it to "nvidia-driver-450-server" as this was the only option with version before 460.
[image: Additional Drivers]
Though this fixed the original problem I had, I still am not sure which driver version to use, being new to linux I don't have much idea about this.

Update : updated to nvidia-driver-470 and it is fixed in that version.